# Vertically align vertical text in booktabs and multirows

Tags: vertical-alignment, multirow, booktabs

I am trying to create a table such as the one presented here, but the text within the first two columns should be centered vertically. However, I am not able to achieve it. What am I doing wrong? I have a warning of "bad \vbox", which I guess its causing the problem, but I do not know how to solve it.

[image]

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    ngerman,
    accentcolor=9c,% Farbe für Hervorhebungen auf Basis der Deklarationen in den
    type=intern,
    marginpar=false
]{tudapub}
\usepackage[english, main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
            \toprule
            &%
            & Central Layer%
            & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Top Layer}%
            \\
            \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
            \cmidrule(lr){4-7}
            &%
            & X = 0 \& Z = -2b%
            & X = 0 \& Z = 0%
            & X = 0 \& Z = 2b%
            & X = 0 \& Z = -2b%
            & X = ann \& Z = 0%
            \\%
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Resonance frequency, $f_\mathrm{0}$ = 81.3 GHz}}%
            & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{E-field}%
            & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4cm]{example-image}%
            & 2%
            & 3%
            & 4%
            & 5%
            \\%
            &\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{H-field}%
            & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4cm]{example-image}%
            & 2%
            & 3%
            & 4%
            & 5%
            \\%
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about the vertical alignment of the contents in the "Top Layer" columns. Do you want these contents vertically centered with respect to the image as well? If so, add `valign=c` to the options of `\includegraphics` and place `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` in the preamble of the document.

Comment: @leandriis worked like a charm! If you want to write it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted :) Thank you

Comment: @leandriis I tried a little bit more and its only the "E-field" and "H-field" the text that is centered now. The part corresponding to "Resonance frequency" still is bottom-aligned, owing to a bad box. Do you have any idea of what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `valign=c` from `adjustbox`, `\Block` and `NiceTabular` from `nicematrix` and `\makebox[0pt]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[
    ngerman,
    accentcolor=9c,% Farbe für Hervorhebungen auf Basis der Deklarationen in den
    type=intern,
    marginpar=false
]{tudapub}
\usepackage[english, main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \centering
        \begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}
            \toprule
            &%
            & Central Layer%
            & \Block{1-4}{Top Layer}%
            \\
            \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
            \cmidrule(lr){4-7}
            &%
            & X = 0 \& Z = -2b%
            & X = 0 \& Z = 0%
            & X = 0 \& Z = 2b%
            & X = 0 \& Z = -2b%
            & X = ann \& Z = 0%
            \\%
            \midrule
            \Block{2-1}{\rotate Resonance frequency, $f_\mathrm{0}$ = 81.3 GHz}%
            & \Block{1-1}{\rotate \makebox[0pt]{E-field}}
            & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4cm, valign=c]{example-image}%
            & 2%
            & 3%
            & 4%
            & 5%
            \\%
            & \Block{1-1}{\rotate \makebox[0pt]{H-field}}
            & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4cm, valign=c]{example-image}%
            & 2%
            & 3%
            & 4%
            & 5%
            \\%
            \bottomrule
        \end{NiceTabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!